# jQuery - how to calculate a product price from a table of product names, quantity ranges and price ranges

Tags: jquery, query-optimization

I have 3 products `A, B, C`

Then I have 2 addons for those products, : `1, 2`

Then I have table of price ranges vs quantity ranges. See below

**PRODUCT vs QUANTITY PRICES**

```
+---------------+--------+----------+
|    Product    |  Qty   |  Price   |
+---------------+--------+----------+
|       A       | 0-10   |    $2    |
|       A       | 10-20  |    $1    |
+---------------+--------+----------+
|       B       | 0-10   |    $3    |
|       B       | 10-20  |    $2    |
+---------------+--------+----------+
|       C       | 0-10   |    $4    |
|       C       | 10-20  |    $3    |
+---------------+--------+----------+
```

**PRODUCT VS ADDON PRICES**

```
+---------------+----------+----------+
|    Product    |  AddOn   |  Price   |
+---------------+----------+----------+
|       A       | 1        |    $2    |
|       A       | 2        |    $1    |
+---------------+----------+----------+
|       B       | 1        |    $3    |
|       B       | 2        |    $2    |
+---------------+----------+----------+
|       C       | 1        |    $4    |
|       C       | 2        |    $3    |
+---------------+----------+----------+
```

- Products are setup as `radio` buttons
- Addonons are setup as `radio` buttons
- Quantity is setup as an `input` field

**My question**

How do I calculate the cost of a product based on what people select from above. I currently have a very long script that does this, but I want to optimise and use `arrays` or maybe `2d arrays` and do it the proper way.  [The current script is here](http://wristbandmonkey.com.au/wp-content/uploads/newjs2.js) .

And [this is the  webpage I have setup](https://wristbandmonkey.com.au/test/) with this functionality.

Thanks A LOT in advance!

Comment: Yes i wrote it manually. Yes its wrong, but it does the job. But its time to use functionas and arrays, but im clue less :)

Comment: I cannot correlate your graphs above with your question and the demo website and clearly I have no intention to run trough 3600 lines of JS :D Can you please explain a bit better what you mean by *"How do I calculate the cost of a product based on what people select from above"* What's selectable and how it works?

Comment: I'll explain how people use this form. They select a band style, then 2nd style, then enter the quantity. If you can look at the pricing table on this page https://wristbandmonkey.com.au/silicone-wristband-prices/. When customers enter the quantity and select the band, i want to calcualte the total cost based on the PER BAND price. Let me know if im not clear, happy to write again in a different way

Comment: `Total Cost = Quantity  X Per band`
People can add `individually wrap` as well. `Individually wrap cost = Quantity X $0.05`. Then it gets added to the Grand Total . `Grand Total = Total Cost + Individually Wrap`

Comment: Is there a quantity - discount ratio? OR is irrational?

Comment: Yes, the higher the quantity, lower the PER BAND cost as shown on this page https://wristbandmonkey.com.au/silicone-wristband-prices/

But no particular ratio or percentage. Just the price gets lower as the quantity goes higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an array of quantities `OB.qtty` and radios `name="product"` and `name="style"` you can find which ones are `:checked` and combine both `values` i.e: `p1` (for the product 1) and `s2` (for the style 2) and get the `OB["p1s2"]` array of prices `pric`.

Now (see example below) `pric` holds this array

```
[2.10, 2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40]
```

and we have the predefined quantity ranges `OB.qtty`:

```
[  50,  100,  150,  200,  250]
```

now all you need to do is to: get the user's desired quantity of items; find out what's the `OB.qtty` respective range key.
Say the user enters `160` items quantity, to find out the `OB.qtty` key index use `.some()`<sup>[.some() MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)</sup> (or create a for loop if you need to support **IE<9**) and use that key index to get the `pric[qIdx]` into `itemPrice` (*results in:* `1.8`).
To add decimals $`1.80` use `.tofixed(2)`

```js
var OB = {
  wrap : 0.05,
  // quantities
  qtty : [  50,  100,  150,  200,  250],
  // product 1
  p1s1 : [2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40, 1.20],
  p1s2 : [2.10, 2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40],
  p1s3 : [2.25, 2.15, 2.05, 1.95, 1.75],
  // product 2
  p2s1 : [3.00, 2.80, 2.60, 2.40, 2.20],
  p2s2 : [3.10, 3.00, 2.80, 2.60, 2.40],
  p2s3 : [3.50, 3.30, 3.00, 2.80, 2.50]
};

function calculate() {
  
  var pVal = $("[name=product]:checked").val();           // "p1", "p2" ?
  var sVal = $("[name=style]:checked").val();             // "s1", "s2", "s3" ?
  var qVal = parseInt($("[name=quantity]").val(), 10)||0; // quantity input
  var wVal = $("[name=wrap]:checked").val();              // (wrap) "yes", "no" ?
  var pric = OB[pVal+sVal]; // i.e: OB["p1s3"]            // (returns: array of prices)

  var qIdx = 0;
  OB.qtty.some(function(v, i) {
    qIdx = i;
    return v >= qVal;
  });
  
  var itemPrice = pric[qIdx];
  var wrapPrice =  wVal==="yes" ? (qVal * OB.wrap) : 0;
  var total = (qVal * itemPrice) + wrapPrice;
  
  $("[name=total]").val( total.toFixed(2) );
  
}

$("[name=product], [name=style], [name=wrap]").on("change", calculate);
$("[name=quantity]").on("input", calculate);
calculate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Products</h3>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="product" value="p1" checked> Product 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="product" value="p2"> Product 2
</label>

<h3>Styles</h3>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="style" value="s1" checked> Style 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="style" value="s2"> Style 2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="style" value="s3"> Style 3
</label>

<h3>Quantity</h3>

<input type="number" name="quantity" value="150">

<h3>Wrap individually</h3>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="wrap" value="no" checked> No
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="wrap" value="yes"> Yes (+ $0.05 per item)
</label>

<h3>Price</h3>
$<input name="total" value="" readonly>
```

Note that the above is not ideal, I'd rather ask the client what are the mathematical relations between product *vs* style *vs* quantity. (That's what was confusing me from the start...). Otherwise you'll find your-self creating load of price/style Arrays.

**Hope that helped...**

Comment: hey, thanks, the script is almost right. But small problem. I have to check radio button combinations before deciding the price. For an example, price for Embossed & Solid is different to Embossed & Print. Thats why I check combinations in my newjs2 script. I have created a fiddle and added a new set of radio buttons, can you please show me how to select combinations and calcualte the price? Thanks a lot. FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/sg04ud7s/5/

Comment: I haven't updated the prices in the fiddle they are sample. So heres the relation : If someone selects Plain & Segmented the price ranges are different set of prices to selecting Plain & Glow inthe dark. Glow in the dark, debossed, embossed bands are more expensive, than plain, so if someone wants plain & segmented, its cheaper set of prices, than selecting plain & glow in the dark. So if that happends I want to pull a different set of prices. The quantity ranges is the same, but the price range changes based on the style selected. Am i clear enough?

Comment: Ok. Now `a` is selected its $2.42 (for 50 quantity) right? but When `a && g` is selected it is a different price, for an example  $2.95(for 50 qty). So to be honest, TYPE is one radio group and STYLE is another radio group. People should select ONE OF EACH GROUP to get the right price. and Both radio groups are `required` so they HAVE to select one of each. Then we have to see 2 combinations are selected, then based on that show the price.

Comment: Right now theres only one group caled `product`, but I need two, `product` and `style` and based on the combination selected, then only we can calcualte the price. Am i clear? Thanks a lot

Comment: Added a completely new (similar) example. @nasty. Hope you'll understand why I did not got your thoughts immediately - reading the last paragraph. Hope it does what you were asking for! (finally).

Comment: Thats what I was stuck at. Thanks a lot Roko. hey do you do fre_elance work? We might be able to work on some fun projects. Let me know :)

Comment: Hey @Roko, sorry to bug you. I have a question related to this calculator. Are you able to help at all? Here it is if you can. Thanks so much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376109/calculate-backwards-in-a-javascript-array