# Calculate backwards in a Javascript array

Tags: jquery, query-optimization

Heres my currently [working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5n1ymeo/).

I have 2 products `1 and 2`

Then I have 3 STYLES for those products a user MUST select : `s1,s2 and s3`

Then I have table of prices that changes with the quantity and style people choose. See below

This is my array.

**Quantity**

`Quantity : [  50,  100,  150,  200,  250]`

**Product 1 prices for all 3 styles**

`p1s1 : [2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40, 1.20]
 p1s2 : [2.10, 2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40]
 p1s3 : [2.25, 2.15, 2.05, 1.95, 1.75]`

**Product 2 prices for all 3 styles**

`p2s1 : [3.00, 2.80, 2.60, 2.40, 2.20]
 p2s2 : [3.10, 3.00, 2.80, 2.60, 2.40]
 p2s3 : [3.50, 3.30, 3.00, 2.80, 2.50]`

Heres my currently [working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5n1ymeo/).

**My question**

I want to create a new calculator that works backwards. That is, when someone inputs the amount of money they have in hand, let's say $250, the calculator should display how many (quantity) Product 1s and 2s someone can purchase with that money. So it should display like below.

**Product 1, Style 1 - Qty 150 = $240**

**Product 1, Style 2 - Qty 138 = $248.40**

**Product 1, Style 3 - Qty 121 = $248.05**

Let me know if Im not clear. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: check out the knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getAffordibiltyObject(OB, money)
{
    var afford = {};
    for (var code in OB){
        if(/p\ds\d/.test(code)){
            for (var i=0; i<OB[code].length; i++){
                if(money < OB[code][i]*OB.qtty[i] || i==OB[code].length-1){
                    var price = OB[code][i];
                    var quantity = Math.floor(money/price);
                    var total = quantity*price;
                    afford[code] = [quantity, total];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return afford;
}


var OB = {
    wrap : 0.05,
    // quantities
    qtty : [  50,  100,  150,  200,  250],
    // product 1
    p1s1 : [2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40, 1.20],
    p1s2 : [2.10, 2.00, 1.80, 1.60, 1.40],
    p1s3 : [2.25, 2.15, 2.05, 1.95, 1.75],
    // product 2
    p2s1 : [3.00, 2.80, 2.60, 2.40, 2.20],
    p2s2 : [3.10, 3.00, 2.80, 2.60, 2.40],
    p2s3 : [3.50, 3.30, 3.00, 2.80, 2.50]
};

var money = 250;


var affordibilityOB = getAffordibiltyObject(OB, money);
```

This is what you are looking for affordibilityOB will be an object with keys like p1s1 , p2s2 ... and the values will be an array of length two first element being result quantity and second being result total.

Comment: Thanks @Vikas. Sorry im quite new to JS. Are you able to do a jsfiddle for me?

Comment: Did you write a new one?  jsfiddle.net/t5n1ymeo is my current code

Comment: you are a legend bro. Hey I like to do a paypal payment for you. Please tell me your paypal id :)

Comment: Thanks man :) 
You can send it to this https://www.paypal.me/srichakradhar

Comment: Hey Vikas, looks like there is a small issue with the calculation. Example : If i enter $100, p1s1 should be $2 per product and 50 in quantity. But it shows $1.2 per product and 83 quantity. Looks like all teh prices are wrong. Do you know why? It ways picks the last pricing bracket See this https://jsfiddle.net/5jppxa53/1/

Comment: sorry missed on condition there.
This one is correct for sure: https://jsfiddle.net/412nuzrt/

And actually you can buy Qty 55 of p1s1 in below $100 (i.e. $99 = $1.8 per product)

Comment: Thanks. But now when I put $500, and $1000 everything disappears.

Comment: Thats what happens when you don't test. :P

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/m4ct9g29/

Comment: Awesome. Sorry to be a pain, but can i ask for one last thing. I have different array names so instead of p1s1 and p1s2, i have PrintedSolid & DebossedInkFilledSolid. Can you show me how to integrate them into the script? Heres the updated link https://jsfiddle.net/m4ct9g29/2/

Comment: @nasty (BTW, hi!) the original script uses Object properties as `pNsN` and Vikas solution tackles with that exact property names structure (not in an ideal way to be honest...), so logically names like *PrintedSolid* and *WhateverElse* do not fit into the logic.

Comment: This is the last one man :P
Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/afc8tv4a/

Its a very simple change where we filter out the codes (keys in object) which have to process. Just look at the change you will understand. For now i did it for you :)

Comment: @nasty if *printed solid*, *embossed*, *debossed* or whatever are your `s` _*Styles*_ `s1, s2` than you don't need to repeat yourself, simply apply those values into Products `p1s1`, `p1s2` etc...

Comment: Thanks @VikasSingh. This stuff is amazing. Thanks a lot for your hard work. Hey I tried to send you a small donation but your paypal says you are unable to receive money.  https://postimg.org/image/uzzy2c1td/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks :)

Comment: @nasty can you share your email id?