# What's the best way to go about calculating data with multiple facets?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'll try and keep this simple, but I'm creating a internal-use calculator for my team to figure out our pricing for t-shirts we sell.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9J2n.png

We have a pricing grid like this one. So I have a place where you can enter the quantity and the number of colors for the screen print. How can I cleanly, without some sort of horrible nested if-then structure, store this information for use in my calculations?

I've tried an array, but I'm just not sure of the best method to organize.

```js
if (parseInt(this.qty, 10) < 36) return
if (parseInt(this.qty, 10) <= 72) return 0.85
if (parseInt(this.qty, 10) <= 144) return 0.75
if (parseInt(this.qty, 10) <= 288) return 0.65
```

Obviously this is a horrible way to do it, but this works. Kinda. I need a good way to include the number of colors in the calculation without this mess of if statements.

What's the best method to go about this? I don't even need specific code, just an idea in theory. This is sort of a learning project for me, so I want to do it myself, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In particular pay attention to the section that talks about not asking subjective questions. By rephrasing this to avoid using the word "best" it should be possible to get a good answer. Is Vue.js relevant at this point in your question?

Comment: While not quite a duplicate question this one is close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040330/jquery-how-to-calculate-a-product-price-from-a-table-of-product-names-quantit

Comment: @JasonAller Thank you for the information. I'll read up before posting future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would store key-value pairs in a pricing object where the key is the upper or lower limit for a quantity price, and the value is the upper/lower limit for the price multiplier.  Like this:

```
var pricingMap = {36: 1, 72: 0.85, 144: 0.75, 288: 0.65};

function getDiscount(qty){
    for (var upper in pricingMap) {
        if (parseInt(this.qty, 10) < upper)
            return pricingMap[upper];
    }
}
```

This way, it is simple to add more quantity ranges and discounts.